# Halting Symbol Transformations for Function Arguments

Tags: evaluation, symbols

I think the simplest way to state my question is to give an example:

```
x=2;
f[x_]:= x;

(* Is this possible? *)
f[x]
(* x *)
```

In other words, is it possible to stop Mathematica from evaluating x as 2 before evaluating the function? None of the Hold attributes or functions have successfully halted this part of evaluation for me.

What I'm trying to do  is pass symbols to a function for it to manipulate, but I don't want to worry about the same symbol names being used in other parts of the code. Using Clear works, but it then requires me to re-evaluate the areas where the symbol name was used before, so I was hoping there was an easier way other than clearing or using different symbol names.

Edit:
Sorry for the confusion. m_goldberg correctly guessed what I was trying to explain. Although I can hide global variables in Module blocks by using the same variable names, I was hoping for the same results with a function.
Here is his code that represents my goal:

```
x = 2;
SetAttributes[f,HoldFirst]
f[x_]:= Module[{u = Defer[x]}, 1 + u + u^2];

f[x]
```

> `1 + x + x^2`

In other words, I wanted to arbitrarily pick symbols as arguments to a function, regardless if they had been assigned values prior to calling my function. Apparently, I was looking for Defer.

I think it's worth noting that jjc385's answer also achieved my goal, but with a hold on the result.

Thank you everybody for the help!

Comment: If `f` is e.g. `HoldFirst` then `x` is not evaluated before `f's` rules are applied. But later, nothing stops it, you can add `f[x_]:= Hold[x];` or something. Could you elaborate on what is the goal?

Comment: I'm trying to make a function that takes in 2 lists, one being a list of equations and the latter being a list of variables. I then manipulate those symbolic variables and equations with other functions and rules and such. I was just hoping there was a way to arbitrarily pick variable names without disrupting other parts of my code, similar to a namespace in other programming languages, but I'll survive if it's not possible. I'm assuming Hold[function_body] may work, but then the assigned symbols would be evaluated immediately after. I would check but I'm not at my work computer currently.

Comment: It sounds like you want the scoping that `Module` provides...?

Comment: Please provide a small example of input, transformations, expected output. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

The normal evaluation of arguments can be overridden by giving a function the appropriate `Hold...` attribute.

```
x = 2;
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_] := Module[{u = Defer[x]}, 1 + u + u^2]

f[x]
```

> `1 + x + x^2`

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but perhaps this is a start.

Based on your [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146376/halting-symbol-transformations-for-function-arguments#comment393387_146376), it seems like you may be roughly trying to mimic the behavior of either [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) or [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) :

```
(* x, y already have explicit values *)
x=1;
y=2;

Module[{x, y},
 First @ Solve[{x + y == 5, x - y == 1}, {x, y}]
]
```

> ```
> {3, 2}
> ```

If the returned expression doesn't depend on any of the previously defined variables (as is the case above), `Module` and `Block` should give you the same output.

If the returned expression does depend on the previously defined variables, neither output may be desirable:

```
(* x, y already have explicit values *)
x=1;
y=2;

Module[{x, y},
 First @ Solve[{x + y == 5, x - y == 1}, {x, y}]
]
```

> ```
> {x$9834 -> 3, y$9834 -> 2}
> ```

```
Block[{x, y},
 First @ Solve[{x + y == 5, x - y == 1}, {x, y}]
]
```

> ```
> {1 -> 3, 2 -> 2}
> ```

I'm guessing you won't ever want the `Block`-style output.  You can mitigate this using [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html):

```
Block[{x, y},
 Hold @@ {First @ Solve[{x + y == 5, x - y == 1}, {x, y}]}
]
```

> ```
> Hold[{x -> 3, y -> 2}]
> ```

You can see I've used the trick of [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)ing (`@@`ing) `Hold` to `{expr}`, so that `expr` evaluates before getting wrapping in `Hold`.

You can turn this into a function using something like

```
ClearAll[myBlock]
SetAttributes[myBlock, HoldAll]

myBlock[varList_List, expr_] :=
 Block[varList,
  Hold @@ {expr}
 ]
```

Then you can do what you asked for in your original question, albeit with a `Hold` wrapper:

```
myBlock[{x}, f[x]]
```

> ```
>  Hold[x]
> ```

Comment: replacing `Hold` with `HoldForm` at least in this case produces the desired output `f[x]`. loved your trick btw. i can see using it for my inspect function which produces an Echo with an automatically generated label for Symbols but does not play well with arguments which are patterns. i use for quick and dirty debugging inside function definitions and native structures.

Comment: @Jules I'm glad to hear this post could help someone ~5 years later :)